# Sugar ORM order by

Tags: android, sql, database, sugarorm, sql-order-by

I'm using sugar ORM in Android to manage my data, but when I receive a list I want to order it in the query using "order by" but I don't find a real example of how to use it. Could somebody please give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: do you already read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565108/sugarorm-orderby-related-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SugarOrm: OrderBy related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565108/sugarorm-orderby-related-table)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
List<BookTbl> list =   Select.from(BookTbl.class)
            .where(Condition.prop("Title").eq("my_")
            .orderBy("ISBN")
            .list();
```

Or :

```
List<BookTbl>  list =   DetailFileObserveTbl.findWithQuery(BookTbl.class,
        "SELECT * FROM Book_Tbl WHERE Title=? ORDER BY ISBN",
        "my_" );
```